# Coloring NSTableView Text per row

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, text-coloring

I have a NSTableView that is displaying an array of objects I have. For each of these objects (rows) I would like to change the color of the text displayed depending on the results of a function I run on each object;

So for example all the object in the table that exist in another list (or some other requirement) I want to display them in green text, and objects that don't exist display in red.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you have [NSTextFieldCell](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextFieldCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in your table (for other cells, setting text color may vary), you can achieve this by implementing a [NSTableView](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s delegate method.

First, you have to define a delegate for the [NSTableView](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), either in Interface Builder or in your code. This can be your application controller for example.

Then, just implement the following method:

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView willDisplayCell:(id)aCell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    NSTextFieldCell *cell = aCell;
    if (...) {
        [cell setTextColor:[NSColor greenColor]];
    } else if (...) {
        [cell setTextColor:[NSColor redColor]];
    } else {
        [cell setTextColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
    }
}
```

Each time the NSTableView will draw a cell, you have the opportunity to modify it before it get drawn.

Check out the [NSTableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) documentation page for more details.

Comment: In the table I am using i have only NSTextFieldCell's but what if I had different would this method not work as is?

Comment: Well, not all cells have "textColor" and "setTextColor:" methods, like the NSButtonCell. It is just a thing to check.